# In React App.js how to conditionally render a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Hnavbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
            <Route path="/analytics" element={<Analytics />}></Route>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />}></Route>
            <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />}></Route>
            <Route path="/nearby-hospitals" element={<Hospitals />}></Route>
            <Route path="/subscribe" element={<Subscribe />}></Route>
          </Routes>
          <ToastContainer theme="light" />
        </div>
      </UserProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my main `App.js` code of React. Now I want that in signup and signin pages, `Navbar` should not be visible. So to do that?

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const isAuthPage = location.pathname === "/signin" || location.pathname === "/signup";

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          {!isAuthPage && <Navbar />}
          <Hnavbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route path="/analytics" element={<Analytics />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
            {/* Rest of the routes */}
            {/* ... */}
          </Routes>
          <ToastContainer theme="light" />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

I tried this with the help of `uselocation` to get current url path but it gave me error `history.ts:480 Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Comment: You have to move that logic to a `Navbar` component or create a wrapper component for `Navbar`

Comment: @Konrad this answer is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use `React-router-dom` hooks just inside of Router provider
acutely you are using the `useLocation` hook before the definition of the Router

you better use HOC to render them. something like this :

```
    const Layout = ({children})=>{
       const location = useLocation();
       const isAuthPage = location.pathname === "/signin" || location.pathname === "/signup";

       return(
             <>
               {!isAuthPage && <Navbar />}
               {children}
             </>
       )
    }
```

then wrap whole the pages with `Layout`